# How do I install the Tor browser in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, tor

Good afternoon. I wanted to install the Tor browser on my computer but I can not make it work. I downloaded the application and tried to follow the instructions but when I called to make a specific command to run I could not do it. The command is './start-tor.browser.desktop --help' Does anyone know what the problem?

Comment: I am sorry but Ubuntu 12.04 is no longer supported on Askubuntu.com and has become an 'end of support release' which means that you will probably not find continued help for Ubuntu 12.04. However, you can always upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: 12.04 is still supported and will be till 2017.

Answer (score 2):

The correct command is `./start-tor-browser` from the directory where it is installed. But I suggest another easier way.

You can install tor-browser from ppa. Run in terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

You will be able to start it from launcher as other programs.